# What spider is this? Is it dangerous to humans?

Tags: species-identification

**What is the species? Is it dangerous to humans?**

I chanced upon this beautiful one near our water well. It stood at a height where an adult could accidentally walk through the web and the spider would land on one's face.

As a test, I dropped a piece of leaf onto its web, and the spider jumped to action, checking what it was and it took out the leaf from its web.

**Size:** Web, almost circular 50 cm diameter. Spider, about 8cm.
**Location:** Malabar region, Kerala state, south of India

[image: a close-up]

[image: from location]

Comment: Most spiders are harmless (unless you're a bug). [Here are the medically significant ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_medically_significant_spider_bites).

Comment: Im in Kochi (same state in India) and I was told it would sting, so stay away. I also remember them as they appear to have only four legs (with claws) and jokes that they defy their very name, which means 8-legs in Malayalam.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is most likely a spider from the genus *[Argiope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_(spider))*, which has a few members native to India. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spiders_of_India#IV_Family_Araneidae_Simon.2C_1895) for a list, I think this is most likely 
*[Argiope pulchella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_pulchella)*, see the image from the Wikipedia:

[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_(spider)#Bite) also says that these spiders hunt insects, but are not dangerous for humans.

Comment: What are your thoughts about @Thomo's answer?

Comment: Its definitely an Argiope pulchella - Native to India, rather than an Argiope keyrselingii (Australian species). Either way, its completely harmless to humans, as are most spiders...

Answer (score 9):

It's a St. Andrews Cross Spider (Argiope keyrselingi), and quite common in Australia too.

[image: Added picture for reference]

Thankfully, one of the non-toxic non aggressive spiders. Here are some good sites for further information on them:

A Spider Identification site:
http://www.spiders.com.au/st-andrews-spider.html

And the Australian Museum site:
http://australianmuseum.net.au/st-andrews-cross-spider